# JS | Slicing a polygon that has an image clipped to it, into two polygons

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm drawing a polygon to the canvas, which has an image clipped inside of it.

On touch start and end, I'm slicing that polygon into two polygons and rotating them and pushing them away from each other. Similar functionality to Fruit Ninja.

My issue is drawing the image to the new polygons, so make it look like you have sliced the image in half and it's now rotating away.

Does anyone have any advice. I don't necessarily need code, I just need to understand how it's done so I can program it.

Thanks heaps.

Comment: If you are rotating and translating the polygon  just keep the same transform for the image when you render it. If you are doing the transform in code then you should lookup the 2D context transform functions `transform`, `setTransform`, `rotate`, `scale`, and `translate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinite designs are possible, but for example...

- Use `translate` to set the rotation point outside the polygon.
- `rotate` to a positive angle and draw the left half of the poly.
- Reset the transformations.
- Use `translate` to set the rotation point outside the polygon.
- `rotate` to a negative angle and draw the right half of the poly.
- Reset the transformations.

Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var cx=50;
var cy=20;
var r=20;
var angle=0;
ctx.fillStyle='salmon';
ctx.strokeStyle='forestgreen';
ctx.lineWidth=3;
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function draw(angle){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

  // left side
  ctx.translate(cx,cy+40);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,r,Math.PI/2,Math.PI*3/2);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

  // right side
  ctx.translate(cx,cy+40);
  ctx.rotate(-angle);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,r,Math.PI*3/2,Math.PI/2);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}

function animate(){
  draw(angle);
  angle+=Math.PI/720;
  if(angle<Math.PI/4){ requestAnimationFrame(animate); }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>
```

Comment: I actually got this sorted not long after you posted this. Pretty much exactly what I did. Thanks for the help.